# Using abs function in join statement in X++ does not work

Tags: sql-server, axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I want to get related BOMVersion of Prodtable records. There is a method in prod table named bomversion :

```
 public BOMVersion bomVersion()
    {
        BOMVersion bomVersion;

        // need to remove active from the query
        select firstonly bomVersion
            order by ItemId, Active, FromQty desc
            where bomVersion.ItemId         == this.ItemId          &&
                  bomVersion.bomId          == this.bomId           &&
                  bomVersion.FromQty        <= abs(this.QtySched)   &&
                  bomVersion.FromDate       <= this.bomDate         &&
                  (bomVersion.ToDate        >= this.bomDate         ||
                   ! bomVersion.ToDate
                  );

        return bomVersion;
    }
```

In other class, I use bom version method logic to know first prodtable record which has a BOMVersion. This is my code:

```
select firstonly * from prodTable
             join bomVersion
            order by ItemId, Active, FromQty desc
            where
                  bomVersion.ItemId       == prodTable.ItemId           &&
                  bomVersion.bomId          == prodTable.bomId          &&
                  bomVersion.FromQty        <= abs(prodTable.QtySched)  && // abs does not work
                  bomVersion.FromDate       <= prodTable.bomDate        &&
                  (bomVersion.ToDate        >= prodTable.bomDate
                    || !bomVersion.ToDate);
```

As I debugged I understood that this code returns no RecId. After commenting one by one where conditions, I noticed that the issue is related to abs method. when I remove abs method form the statement (I mean replace the condition with  bomVersion.FromQty <= prodTable.QtySched ), record is found. But when I put abs no record is found. I should mention that I try this query in SQL server and in the two cases i.e. using abs and without abs, It finds records.
Actually I can't understand what is the reason. Because this abs method is used in select statement in Prodtable bomversion method. Why this problem is not exist there?

Comment: You cannot use functions in where statements if result could not be "precalculated" before query execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use X++ functions in select clauses but they are evaluated *once* before the trip to the SQL server. This is not what you want here.

In this case you can unroll the `abs` function:

```
select firstonly prodTable
    join bomVersion
    order by ItemId, Active, FromQty desc
    where bomVersion.ItemId         == prodTable.ItemId         &&
          bomVersion.bomId          == prodTable.bomId          &&
        ((bomVersion.FromQty        <= prodTable.QtySched       && prodTable.QtySched >= 0) ||
         (bomVersion.FromQty        <=-prodTable.QtySched       && prodTable.QtySched <  0))                  
          bomVersion.FromDate       <= prodTable.bomDate        &&
         (bomVersion.ToDate         >= prodTable.bomDate        || !bomVersion.ToDate);
```

Do you ever plan a negative production?

Another way to do is to make [a view with a computed field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/walkthrough-add-a-computed-column-to-a-view). In the compute field function you may apply any SQL function available.

Comment: Dear Jan , Thank you I want to know more about "They are evaluated once before the trip to the SQL server" is there any article about that?

Comment: No, that was from the top of my head :) You can find similar questions by googling, https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ax+2012%22+%22select%22+function&oq=%22ax+2012%22+%22select%22+function